# Evitar doble submit en campos con validación

Tags: javascript, html, c#, css, asp.net

Estoy realizando un proyecto en asp.net con boostrap, html y css.

Tengo un código para ocultar los botones al darles clic para que al momento de procesar el usuario no pueda darle clic mas veces, funciona bien, solo que al tener validados los campos, si estos campos están vacíos no ejecuta la acción de botón, pero de igual manera se oculta el botón y no hay manera de desactivarlo.

¿Hay alguna forma de no desactivar el botón si los campos no están validados?

Este es mi código:

```
<div class="pricing-month" >
    <p class="bts">Complete los siguientes campos y adjunte su CV en formato .doc, .docx o .pdf</p>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNombre1" CssClass= "form-control" placeholder = "Nombre completo" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfNombre1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Debe capturar los campos solicitados" ValidationGroup="VG1" ControlToValidate="txtNombre1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br/>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail1" CssClass= "form-control" placeholder = "E-mail para contacto" CausesValidation="True" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfEmail1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Debe capturar los campos solicitados" ControlToValidate="txtEmail1" ValidationGroup="VG1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <hr/>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="fup"/>
    <hr/>
    <script >
        function deshabilitar(boton) {
                document.getElementById(boton).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="btnPost1" runat="server" Text="Postularse" CssClass="btn btn-default section-btn" OnClick="btnPost1_Click" causesvalidation="true" ValidationGroup="VG1" OnClientClick = "deshabilitar(this.id)" Visible="true"/>

 </div>
```

---

Lo he intentado de ambas formas pero no me ha funcionado ninguna, he modificado un poco mi codigo y es lo que tengo:

```
<div class="pricing-month" >
                            <p class="bts">Complete los siguientes campos y adjunte su CV en formato .doc, .docx o .pdf</p>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNombre1" CssClass= "form-control" placeholder = "Nombre completo" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfNombre1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Debe capturar los campos solicitados" ValidationGroup="VG1" ControlToValidate="txtNombre1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <br/>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail1" CssClass= "form-control" placeholder = "E-mail para contacto" CausesValidation="True" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfEmail1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Debe capturar los campos solicitados" ControlToValidate="txtEmail1" ValidationGroup="VG1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <hr/>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="fup"/>
                            <hr/>
                            <script >
                                function deshabilitar(boton) {
                                    if (!$('<%= txtNombre1.ClientID %>').val() || !$('<%= rfNombre1.ClientID %>').val() || !$('<%= txtEmail1.ClientID %>').val() || !$('<%= rfEmail1.ClientID %>').val()) {
                                        document.getElementById(boton).style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        document.getElementById(boton).style.visibility = 'visible';
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnPost1" runat="server" Text="Postularse" CssClass="btn btn-default section-btn" OnClick="btnPost1_Click" causesvalidation="true" ValidationGroup="VG1" OnClientClick = "deshabilitar(this.id)" Visible="true"/>
                         </div>
```

En teoria deberia de funcionar, ya que le digo que si alguno de los campos esta vacio NO esconda el boton.

---

gracias por la respuesta.
Lo intente pero me sigue sin funcionar, sigue bloqueando el campo si los campos no estan validados, el codigo quedo asi:

```
<div class="pricing-month" >
                            <p class="bts">Complete los siguientes campos y adjunte su CV en formato .doc, .docx o .pdf</p>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNombre1" CssClass= "form-control" placeholder = "Nombre completo" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfNombre1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Debe capturar los campos solicitados" ValidationGroup="VG1" ControlToValidate="txtNombre1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <br/>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail1" CssClass= "form-control" placeholder = "E-mail para contacto" CausesValidation="True" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfEmail1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Debe capturar los campos solicitados" ControlToValidate="txtEmail1" ValidationGroup="VG1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <hr/>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="fup"/>
                            <hr/>
                            <script >
                                function deshabilitar(boton) {
                                    if(!$("#txtNombre1").val() && !$("#rfNombre1").val() && !$("#txtEmail1").val() && !$("#rfEmail1").val()) 
                                    {
                                        document.getElementById(boton).style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnPost1" runat="server" Text="Postularse" CssClass="btn btn-default section-btn" OnClick="btnPost1_Click" causesvalidation="true" ValidationGroup="VG1" OnClientClick = "deshabilitar(this.id)" Visible="true"/>
                         </div>
```

No se si este algo mal.

Saludos,

Comment: quien invoca a `deshabilitar()` ? Ademas porque pones codigo javascript mezclado con el html, se supone que este deberia estar en el head o al final del html, o mejor aun si esta en un .js separado

Comment: Abajo el boton, @LeandroTuttini. Faltaria alguna forma de ejecutar on post evento de validacion, que si falla lo vuelva a habilitar..

Comment: La funcion se invoca en OnClientClick del boton, en cuanto a lo del codigo planeo poner todos mis scripts en la parte final de la pagina.
Mi duda solo es esa, como podria hacer que si los campos estan vacios/no validados, no se ejecute la funcion deshabilitar()

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría usar un formulario html5 con sus respectivos atributos de validación así te sera más facil validar los campos y saber cuando están todos validados, con esta instrucción puedes saber si todos los campos están validados

```js
const $form = document.getElementById('form-id'); 
if(! $form.checkValidity()){
   document.getElementById('boton').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}else{
   document.getElementById('boton').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que tenes que hacer es preguntar antes en la funcion si los campos estan vacios
aca es lo que haria con jquery:

```
//se validan que no esten vacio, asi se checkea si es falso pero a efectos practicos cumple la misma funcion.
//completalo con el resto de los campos, acordate de preguntar por todos
if(!$("#txtNombre1").val() || !$("#rfNombre1").val() ||...) 
{
  document.getElementById(boton).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

y ahi asi seria , preguntas si cada uno no esta vacio y si uno lo esta no se ocultan los campos

Answer (score 0):

Esta acción la puedes hacer del lado del cliente y de lado del servidor, para el cliente

```
addEventListener("submit", function());
```

con este podrias validar el formulario, pero necesitas hacer formulario tu estructura con

```
<form></form>
```

le haces target y en el evento mientras este validando

```
var form  = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
form.addEventListener("sumbit", function(event,false){// Codigo de verificación aqui});
```

si todo va bien desactiva el boton

```
 document.getElementById(boton).disabled = true;
```

para los inputs tambien hay un evento que valida lo que escribes
por ejemplo para el correo

```
(eltxtBoxt/inputSeleccionado).addEventListener("input", function (event){
  if (email.validity.valid) {
    // In case there is an error message visible, if the field
    // is valid, we remove the error message.
    error.innerHTML = ""; // Reset the content of the message
    error.className = "error"; // Reset the visual state of the message
  }
},false);
```

te puedes apoyar de esta documentacion, alli viene todo
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

y del servidor, seria validar cada txtBox y si no estan bien pues desactivas el button con cada target

Answer (score -1):

Alterando la condicional de tu código, sugiero esta solución:

```
function deshabilitar(boton) {
    if($("#txtNombre1").val() != '' && $("#txtEmail1").val() != '') 
    {
        document.getElementById(boton).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Comment: Si pudieras añadir una breve explicación de tu código tu respuesta quedaría mucho mejor.

Comment: Gracias Angel, es importante revisar [answer] a la hora de realizar respuestas, saludos.